# A question on simplicial groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, simplicial-stuff

Does the adjunction $||:sSet\leftrightarrow Top :Sing$ behave well with respect to simplicial and topological groups in the sense that the unit and the counit maps are maps of group objecs in both categories? (In $Top$ we use compactly generated product.)